# Should I use Indexes on mySql table?

Tags: mysql, index

I have a table in mysql, in which searching, insertion, deletion and updation is done quite frequently and I have read that indexes affection insertion and updation performance. so should I use Indexes for faster searches?

Comment: *I have read that indexes affection insertion and updation performance.* Index affects on ALL operations. It increase selection performance and increase or decrease (or visually not change) altering data performance. *should I use Indexes for faster searches?* Dependent by search type. Some search types cannot be optimized by index.

Comment: We need more information. Give us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE blah\G` and some of your more frequent queries (and their frequencies per sec/min/hour/day/week/month...) as well as the `EXPLAIN` of those queries - without this information, we can't help I'm afraid!

Comment: You _must_ learn about and use indexes to get anywhere nontrivial with databases.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table in mysql, in which searching, insertion, deletion and updation is done quite frequently and I have read that indexes affection insertion and updation performance. so should I use Indexes for faster searches?

Yes, there is an overhead in having indexes when changing data.  As well as updating the base data table, the DBMS also has to update the index structures as well.  That overhead, however, is *small*.  Remember the all changes are [quickly] written to memory first and only flushed [slowly] to disk some time later.

Indexes exist primarily to improve query performance and can do so by *Orders of Magnitude*.  Imagine retrieving a single record by its unique ID:

- If that field is indexed then the DBMS can quickly skip through the index [blocks], then "hop" across to the data page to get any additional fields.
- Without the index the DBMS has to scan *each and every* record in the table.  If that table has *millions* of records, that's going to be really, really slow.  Even with a "limit 1" clause, telling the DBMS to stop at the first match, you'll still be reading *half* the table, on average.

So Indexes are a trade-off.  They can make you [huge] gains on the querying front, while making [small] losses on the update front.  The only person who can *definitively* tell you whether it's worth your while to index your fields is *you*, based on your database and your Application.  **Test** that Application with and without indexes and compare the results.

That said, I strongly suspect you'll come back in favour of using them :-)

Comment: It may be worth noting that indexes also help when updating and deleting rows with a search predicate (ex: update ... where ...)